# newrelic-1.10.2.38/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py self.generator.close() kicking up IOError

Tags: django, uwsgi, gevent, newrelic

Using uwsgi 1.4.2 (gevent = 100) with newrelic, I am encountering repeated errors

```
[pid: 24340|app: 0|req: 1335/4305] 199.27.128.147 () {54 vars in 722 bytes} [Fri Mar 22 16:49:41 2013] HEAD / => generated 0 bytes in 158 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 5 headers in 269 bytes (4 switches on core 99)
IOError: write error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/web/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.10.2.38/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py", line 539, in close
    self.generator.close()
  File "/home/web/.virtualenvs/myproject/src/django/django/http/response.py", line 227, in close
    for closable in self._closable_objects:
IOError: write error
Exception AssertionError: AssertionError() in <generator object __iter__ at 0x4ed2e10> ignored
```

Where can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by use of uwsgi 1.9 which handles gevent properly.

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue on uwsgi 1.9.17.1-debian